# Jagged arrays with jagged columns, rather than jagged rows

Tags: java, jagged-arrays

This is my first time working with jagged arrays, and I am trying to figure out if you can make one with jagged columns, rather than jagged rows (I have searched Google and this site, to no avail). To clarify, I want to make an array with 2 columns; the first column has only one row, and the second column has 3 rows.

```
public class Tester
{
   public static void main (String [] args)
   { 
       int[][] d = new int[3][];

       // First row has 2 columns 
       d[0] = new int[2]; 

       // Second row has 1 column 
       d[1] = new int[1];

       //Third row has 1 column
       d[2] = new int[1]; 

       d[0][0] = 1;
       d[0][1] = 0;
       d[1][0] = 0;
       d[2][0] = 1;
   }
}
```

This code prints out 1, 0, 1 in the first column and 0 in the second column. What I am trying to print is 1 in the first column and 0, 0, 1 in the second column. What should I do differently?

Thanks!!

Comment: I've never seen this type of array. Perhaps you want to emulate this by pivoting the access to a standard jagged array or by using a sparse array.

Comment: A 2d array is just an array of arrays. Whether you consider them rows or columns is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't allow to have variable number of rows, you can have variable number of columns. Always the last bracket in array declaration can be left blank.
Ex:

```
int[][] d = new int[3][];
```

You can achieved the above output by converting your columns into rows. In that case it would be defined like this:

```
   int[][] d = new int[2][];

   // First row has 1 columns 
   d[0] = new int[1]; 

   // Second row has 3 column 
   d[1] = new int[3];

   d[0][0] = 1;
   d[1][0] = 0;
   d[1][1] = 0;
   d[1][2] = 1;
```